# How to solve error in mobX at npm start?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-utils

I get these errors in these files after ***NPM START***. What should i do?

```
ERROR in ./~/mobx-router/src/route.js
ERROR in ./~/mobx-router/src/start-router.js
ERROR in ./~/mobx-router/src/components/MobxRouter.js
ERROR in ./~/mobx-router/src/router-store.js
ERROR in ./~/mobx-router/src/components/Link.js
ERROR in ./~/bstrap-react-mobx-admin/input/text.js
ERROR in ./~/bstrap-react-mobx-admin/input/date.js
ERROR in ./~/bstrap-react-mobx-admin/input/select.js
ERROR in ./~/bstrap-react-mobx-admin/view/edit.js
.
.
.
ERROR in ./~/bstrap-react-mobx-admin/field/bool.js
ERROR in ./~/react-mobx-admin/state/data_table.js
```

All of them are just ***Unexpected token***.
But on the other PC it fully works. What can be wrong? Had aynone same problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are they on the same node version

Comment: I updated NPM and node.js .. Remove lock file, remove node_modules remove cashe and reinstall again. Still not working.

Comment: Could you print the full error for one of the Unexpected token?